# .htaccess Rewrite for State Abbreviations, Ignore Otherwise

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DC|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?state=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I currently have this as my code in my .htaccess file. What I want to happen is ***domain.com/{state}*** to plug whatever state into the state parameter and load its specifics. However, I also want other paths in the domain to work such as ***domain.com/img/flamingo.jpg***. However, the way the code is currently since flamingo has ***fl*** in it, it'll interpret that as the state of Florida and cause a 404 error and not load the resource. How can I do the conditions so that it checks for the state abbreviations only, and then ignores the rewrite in all other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex directly in `RewriteRule` but more importantly use anchors to disallow anything other than state code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(A[LKRZ]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|PA|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AT]|W[AIVY])/?$  index.php?state=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I added a NC to it also, just incase someone typed it in lowercase :)

Comment: Yes indeed `NC can be handy.